# Easiest way to Sum a Column

Tags: excel, vba

Every month I do a pull of 100k+ lines from SAP.  At the bottom of the sheet I create Totals and Subtotals.  Is it possible to create a sum function using the Cells and Rows.Count function or is there an easier way to do this?  This is my code so far

```
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "U").End(xlUp).Row
    Cells(N + 2, "U") = "Total"
    Cells(N + 2, "U") = "Negative Inventory"
    Cells(N + 2, "U") = "Updated Total"
    Cells(N + 5, "U") = "Prior Month Ending"
    Cells(N + 7, "U") = "Difference"
    Cells(N + 1, "V").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(Cells(2, "V"):Cells(N, "V"))" (This is where I am stuck)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Cells(N + 1, "V").Formula = "=SUM(V2:" & Cells(N, "V").address & ")"`.

Comment: Would you need a formula or its outcome?

Comment: Thanks! that worked, what does the .address & do to the equation?

Comment: JvdV either or would work.  Thanks!

Comment: Or `Cells(N + 1, "V").Formula = "=SUM(V2:V" & N & ")"`. `Address` is the long way to the same result.

Comment: @BigBen - yes, well if you want to make life simple...

Comment: If you just need the sum result then you can do `.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("V2:V" & N))`

Comment: @user12553273 ```.address``` returns the address of the range, ```&``` is the concatenation character. It combines strings together. Together they finish out the range used in ```=SUM```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the `SUM` and not a formula that calculates it, then you can use `WorksheetFunction.Sum` here and assign to the cell's `Value`:

```
Cells(N + 1, "V").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("V2:V" & N))
```

Or you can assign to the cell's `Formula`:

```
Cells(N + 1, "V").Value = "=SUM(V2:V" & N)"
```

A `SUBTOTAL` formula might be more semantically accurate for your purpose though, depending on what else is on that sheet and how it's laid out:

```
Cells(N + 1, "V").Value = "=SUBTOTAL(9,V2:V" & N)"
```